# Obtain Related Div Text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

After bit of struggling and few valuable suggestions, I've come into a solution that works well
as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    divs = $(".divs").children();
    divs.each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if (divs.next().length != 0)
            divs.next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            divs.hide();
            divs.show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if (divs.prev().length != 0)
            divs.prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            divs.hide();
            divs.show();
        }
        return false;
    });
    
    $(".btn").click(function() {
    $('.cbCheck:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    var id = $(".h2Val").text();
              alert(id + $(this).val());
     });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
    <div class="heading">
    <div class="h2Val">
     1
    </div>
      <div>What's the capital of England?</div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="val1" class="cbCheck" name="val1" value="London" />London</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val2" class="cbCheck" name="val2" value="New York" />New York</div>
      </div>
      <div>
       <input type="button" class="btn" value="Get Value" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="heading">
    <div class="h2Val">
     2
    </div>
      <div>Who invented computer?</div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val3" class="cbCheck" name="val3" value="Thomas Edison" />Thomas Edison</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val4" class="cbCheck" name="val4" value="Charles Babbage" />Charles Babbage</div>
      </div>
      <div class="heading2">
        <div><input type="checkbox" id="val5" class="cbCheck" name="val5" value="Sir Isaac Newton" />Sir Isaac Newton</div>
      </div>
        <div>
       <input type="button" class="btn" value="Get Value" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a id="prev">Previous</a>
  <a id="next">Next</a>
```

As you can see, I am showing few questions with options to be selected. With the previous and
next button, I can see previous or next question and select the answer. My challenge is when
I select a **CheckBox**, say in div with the class **h2Val**, I require to get the respective number
of that div.

```
1
Ques: What's the capital of England?
Options:
       i) London
      ii) New York
```

Say I selected **London** and when click on the **Get Value** button, it should show me the selected
value as well the number 1 at the top and same for question 2. I tried this one but it gets me all the numbers in the div:

```
$('.cbCheck:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
   var id = $(".h2Val").text(); //Trying to obtain the div text 
   alert(id + $(this).val());
});
```

Anything that I missed here? Any idea would be appreciated - Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".h2Val").text()` gets all text from all matching elements in the selector.

You need to target the instance within the same `.heading` container as the button.
Traverse to the main parent container using `closest()` and use `find()` to only look within that instance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  divs = $(".divs").children();
  divs.each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

  $("#next").click(function() {
    if (divs.next().length != 0)
      divs.next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
      divs.hide();
      divs.show();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#prev").click(function() {
    if (divs.prev().length != 0)
      divs.prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
      divs.hide();
      divs.show();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $(".btn").click(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.heading')
    var id = $container.find(".h2Val").text().trim();
    var $checked = $container.find('.cbCheck:checked');
    var values = $checked.map(function(){
        return this.value
    }).get();
    console.clear()
    console.log('ID: ' + id +' has ' + $checked.length + ' checked');
    console.log('Values: ', values.join())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <div class="heading">
    <div class="h2Val">
      1
    </div>
    <div>What's the capital of England?</div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="val1" class="cbCheck" name="val1" value="London" />London</div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val2" class="cbCheck" name="val2" value="New York" />New York</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn" value="Get Value" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="heading">
    <div class="h2Val">
      2
    </div>
    <div>Who invented computer?</div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val3" class="cbCheck" name="val3" value="Thomas Edison" />Thomas Edison</div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val4" class="cbCheck" name="val4" value="Charles Babbage" />Charles Babbage</div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val5" class="cbCheck" name="val5" value="Sir Isaac Newton" />Sir Isaac Newton</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn" value="Get Value" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a id="prev">Previous</a>
<a id="next">Next</a>
```