# Unable To Get Id and Value From Specific Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling with this thing for the last few days and trying to obtain specific div details. It was resolved actually and here is the working one - [Obtain Related Div Text with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62848550/obtain-related-div-text-with-jquery). So if you have seen it, I was using individual buttons for each div section as follows:

```
<div class="divs">
<div class="heading">
<div class="h2Val"> //Trying to retrieve this value - The id
 1
</div>
  <div>What's the capital of England?</div>
  <div class="heading2">
    <div> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="val1" class="cbCheck" name="val1" value="London" />London</div>
    //Another one is this - CheckBox value
  </div>
  <div class="heading2">
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="val2" class="cbCheck" name="val2" value="New York" />New York</div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="button" class="btn" value="Get Value" /> //This is the button that was assigned with every div
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But now, I am trying to separate the buttons and used anchor tag that's out of the parent div class **divs** to retrieve those values . But the issue is, it doesn't get the id and values of individual divs. Here is the code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  divs = $(".divs").children();
  divs.each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

  var index = 0,
    divs = $(".divs").children();
  $("#next").click(function() {
    index = (index + 1) % divs.length;
    divs.eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
  })
  $("#prev").click(function() {
    index = (index - 1) % divs.length;
    divs.eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
  })

  $(".button").click(function() { //This doesn't get the id and value of heading div
    var $container = $(this).closest('.heading')
    var id = $container.find(".h2Val").text().trim();
    var $checked = $container.find('.cbCheck:checked');
    var values = $checked.map(function(){
        return this.value
    }).get();
    console.clear()
    console.log('ID: ' + id +' has ' + $checked.length + ' checked');
    console.log('Values: ', values.join())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <div class="heading">
    <div class="h2Val">
      1
    </div>
    <div>What's the capital of England?</div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="val1" class="cbCheck" name="val1" value="London" />London</div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val2" class="cbCheck" name="val2" value="New York" />New York</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="heading">
    <div class="h2Val">
      2
    </div>
    <div>Who invented computer?</div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val3" class="cbCheck" name="val3" value="Thomas Edison" />Thomas Edison</div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val4" class="cbCheck" name="val4" value="Charles Babbage" />Charles Babbage</div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val5" class="cbCheck" name="val5" value="Sir Isaac Newton" />Sir Isaac Newton</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="button" id="prev">Previous</a>
<a class="button" id="next">Next</a>
```

So I tweaked a bit with the following but it retrieves all the selected div values at a time rather than individual:

```
 $(".button").click(function() { //This doesn't get the id and value of heading div
        var $container = $('.divs').children().closest('.heading')
        var id = $container.find(".h2Val").text().trim();
        var $checked = $container.find('.cbCheck:checked');
        var values = $checked.map(function(){
            return this.value
        }).get();
        console.clear()
        console.log('ID: ' + id +' has ' + $checked.length + ' checked');
        console.log('Values: ', values.join())
      });
    });
```

Any better way or solution to resolve it?

**Update 1**: Expected output - When checked on first option and clicked **Next**, it should show result as follows:

```
ID: 1  has 1 checked
Values: London
```

Then when second question comes and the same should happen:

```
ID: 2  has 1 checked
Values: Charles Babbage
```

Comment: `$('.divs').children()` OR `$('.divs').find('.heading')` instead of `$('.divs').children().closest('.heading')` .. So try `$('.divs').find('.heading').eq(index);` and see if this is what you want

Comment: Close enough @Mohamed-Yousef and thanks a lot for it. Could you please see my updated post? I've given a sample how the output should appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get length of `.divs` and then declare some variable which will have value `0` .So, whenever next button is clicked you can check if the `variable` value if less then the length of `.divs` and depending on this either `increment` value by 1 or start counter again from `0`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  divs = $(".divs").children();
  divs.each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

  var index = 0,
    divs = $(".divs").children();
  $("#next").click(function() {
    index = (index + 1) % divs.length;
    divs.eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
  })
  $("#prev").click(function() {
    index = (index - 1) % divs.length;
    divs.eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
  })
  //declare
  var indexes = 0;
  $(".button").click(function() { 
  //get div length
    var lengths = divs.length;
    //pass indexes value to get required div
    var $container = $('.divs').children().eq(indexes);
   
    var id = $container.find(".h2Val").text().trim();
    var $checked = $container.find('.cbCheck:checked');
    var values = $checked.map(function() {
      return this.value
    }).get();
    console.clear()
    console.log('ID: ' + id + ' has ' + $checked.length + ' checked');
    console.log('Values: ', values.join())
    //checking if indexes value is less then length of div
    if (indexes < (lengths-1)) {
    //increment
      indexes++;
    } else {
    //start from 0 
      indexes = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs" datas="abc">
  <div class="heading">
    <div class="h2Val">
      1
    </div>
    <div>What's the capital of England?</div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="val1" class="cbCheck" name="val1" value="London" />London</div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val2" class="cbCheck" name="val2" value="New York" />New York</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="heading">
    <div class="h2Val">
      2
    </div>
    <div>Who invented computer?</div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val3" class="cbCheck" name="val3" value="Thomas Edison" />Thomas Edison</div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val4" class="cbCheck" name="val4" value="Charles Babbage" />Charles Babbage</div>
    </div>
    <div class="heading2">
      <div><input type="checkbox" id="val5" class="cbCheck" name="val5" value="Sir Isaac Newton" />Sir Isaac Newton</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="button" id="prev">Previous</a>
<a class="button" id="next">Next</a>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm @Swati. Thanks a lot, can you do one favor if you have time? In the **Previous** and **Next** click event, I am trying to block the events if it reaches the last div. Say the second question is reached and user clicks on **Next** event, it shouldn't go forward but it can go to the previous question. In the same way, **Previous** event should do the same. I tried with this statement but it didn't get me the result as expected - `if(divs.eq(index).next().length != 0)` for next event.

Comment: You mean you need to disable the next button if the last question is reached and same for previous?

Comment: does these data are dynamic ? or static ? Also on click of previous button you need to show that result or not ?

Comment: The data showing are dynamic. For testing purpose, I showed static data at the moment. Yes, when user clicks on the events, it should display respective div data like you have done in the sample code snippet of yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218020/discussion-between-swati-and-at-2017).

Comment: @AT-2017 check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/mLezntd2/11/) if that works for you.

Comment: This worked perfectly except the last one I meant the last question. Rather than that perfect solution. I can handle that in another way but will try to do it as the **Previous** event. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: If you have time, check on this @Swati - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63103847/get-specific-div-content-based-on-id. Thanks.